# How to get user profiles from sharepoint into asp .net core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web, sharepoint, razor-pages

I've built an app through ASP.NET Core, using the Razor Pages approach, but now I need to get the data from the user profiles of a sharepoint page. Actually, I need access to their all their properties.

Is there a way to do this? Or is the sharepoint page that has to send that data to the app?

Answer (score 1):

Using [webApi SharePoint](https://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)

1) Get all properties of current user:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

2) Get single property of current user:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/PictureUrl
```

OR

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl
```

3) Get Multiple Properties for the current user:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl,AccountName
```

4) Get all properties of Specific User:

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|vardhaman@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'
```

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premises:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\username'
```

5) Get Specific UserProfile Property of Specific User:

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|vardhaman@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'
```

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premises:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='domain\username'
```